# ArcGIS Runtime : How to create 3d cube in SceneView with Z?

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I want to draw 3d cube in SceneView by interactive operation.

The functions I hope to achieve are:

1. Click multiple points (x1, y1,0), (x2, y2, 0), (x3, y3, 0), (x4, y4, 0) on SceneView through interaction.
2. Enter the height `h` through the pop-up window.
3. Draw a cube with these points:
   (x1,y1,0),(x2,y2,0),(x3,y3,0),(x4,y4,0),(x1,y1,h),(x2,y2,h),(x3 ,y3,h),(x4,y4,h)

I tried this:

```
var centerPoint = new MapPoint(vm.X, vm.Y, vm.Z, onMapLocation.SpatialReference);

SimpleMarkerSceneSymbol symbol = SimpleMarkerSceneSymbol.CreateCube(System.Drawing.Color.DarkSeaGreen, 1, SceneSymbolAnchorPosition.Center);
symbol.Heading = vm.Heading;
symbol.Height = vm.Height;
symbol.Width = vm.Width;
symbol.Depth = vm.Depth;
// Create the graphic from the geometry and the symbol.
Graphic item = new Graphic(centerPoint, symbol);

// Add the graphic to the overlay.
graphicOverlay.Graphics.Add(item);
```

It works,but I can only get one point from Geometry. I want to get all vertices of my cube.

Then I tried to draw a polygon without Z , and set `Renderer` to display:

```
// Create a new simple line symbol for the feature layer
SimpleLineSymbol mySimpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1);

// Create a new simple fill symbol for the feature layer 
SimpleFillSymbol mysimpleFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbolStyle.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke, mySimpleLineSymbol);

// Create a new simple renderer for the feature layer
SimpleRenderer mySimpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(mysimpleFillSymbol);

// Get the scene properties from the simple renderer
RendererSceneProperties myRendererSceneProperties = mySimpleRenderer.SceneProperties;

// Set the extrusion mode for the scene properties
myRendererSceneProperties.ExtrusionMode = ExtrusionMode.AbsoluteHeight;

// Set the initial extrusion expression
myRendererSceneProperties.ExtrusionExpression = "[Z]";

// Set the feature layer's renderer to the define simple renderer
featureLayer.Renderer = mySimpleRenderer;
```

In my featureLayer, it has a feature `Z`, so it works.
But this does not meet my requirements, I want to draw the cube in real time instead of reading the data.

I don't know how to achieve...
A .NET solution is the best, and other languages are also acceptable.
Finally, please forgive my poor English :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used Render to solve the problem, but I was not satisfied with this solution.
This is my completed result:
https://www.cnblogs.com/Lulus/p/13948464.html